# How to sort this list of strings along with the strings and output the result as expected?

Tags: java, string, data-structures

When the input is:

```
["xL01(F]J","2pn5Mm","-5)8gF{","KWq0P]*%Q","n@,:\u003eAm@","\u003cRN_qCa7","8Qx\u0026RAON","gT~s!1s?4i{K","w\"r^d_#l$Mmp"]
```

Expected output should be:

```
["(01FJL]x","25Mmnp",")-58Fg{","%*0KPQW]q",",:\u003e@@Amn","7\u003cCNR_aq","\u00268ANOQRx","!14?KTgiss{~","\"#$M^_dlmprw"]
```

There are specific Unicode characters (\u003e, \u003c, \u0026) that were being sorted and replaced in a specific way. How to create a solution that could handle these Unicode characters dynamically without explicitly checking for each one individually. By identifying the Unicode characters programmatically, the solution should adapt to any input string containing such characters without requiring manual intervention.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] qArray = { "xL01(F]J", "2pn5Mm", "-5)8gF{", "KWq0P]*%Q", "n@,:\u003eAm@", "\u003cRN_qCa7",
            "8Qx\u0026RAON", "gT~s!1s?4i{K", "w\"r^d_#l$Mmp" };
    List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> qList = Arrays.asList(qArray);
    qList.forEach(qString -> {
        String sorted = sortedString(qString);
        String replacedAndSorted = replaceUnicode(sorted);
        aList.add(replacedAndSorted);
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aList.toArray()));
}

public static String sortedString(String str) {
    char[] c = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c);
    return new String(c);
}

public static String replaceUnicode(String sorted) {
    String replacedString = sorted;
    char[] c = sorted.toCharArray();
    if (sorted.contains("\u003e")) {
        replacedString = sorted.replace("\u003e",
                "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(sorted.codePointAt(sorted.indexOf("\u003e"))));
    }
    if (sorted.contains("\u003c")) {
        replacedString = sorted.replace("\u003c",
                "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(sorted.codePointAt(sorted.indexOf("\u003c"))));
    }
    if (sorted.contains("\u0026")) {
        replacedString = sorted.replace("\u0026",
                "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(sorted.codePointAt(sorted.indexOf("\u0026"))));
    }
    return replacedString;
}
```

Comment: You can use a regular expression to find non-ASCII characters (i.e., characters with a code point greater than 127) in the sorted string, then replace each non-ASCII character with its Unicode escape sequence (i.e., `\uxxxx` for BMP characters)

Comment: But the code point of the given unicode characters are not greater than 127.

Comment: Do you realise that "\u003e" is equal to ">"? Your input string has no special characters nor literal `\u003e`. This has nothing to do with sorting. I don't really understand why you would want to **insert** literal `\u003e` in the output, when you don't have that in your input.

Comment: There definitely is `\u003e` in both the input and the output. Check this `"n@,:\u003eAm@"`

Comment: I think you misunderstand. String literals allow you to encode a character by its unicode, but the result is that you really get a string the has the actual encoded character, so check what this outputs: `"\u003e".equals(">")` and this: `"\u003e".length()`. You seem to think that `"\u003e"` is something else than `">"`. That's a misunderstanding. Either you misrepresent what you *actually* have as input, or you misunderstand what the code in your post provides as input.

Comment: Yes I understood that and that is exactly the problem. It interpreted it as a character but I have to check whether the string has some character written in unicode format. That is the exact problem. Is there anyway to print the required output without explicitly checking and replacing for the characters?

Comment: The input strings don't have "characters written in unicode format". The source code of the program does, but this doesn't affect the contents of the string.

Comment: Your string has no character "written in unicode format". What you have is *code* that encodes a string using an alternative syntax, but the string in memory does not have a trace about that. There ***really*** is no difference with ">". You cannot detect something that is not there. There are two possibilities: either you have simplified your real code to the point that it no longer represents your actual problem, or you are thinking that a string literal syntax feature leaves some trace in memory. I think it is actually the first, but then your question post is wrong.

Comment: First of all, it's a simple question. Can we determine whether it's possible to detect if the string contains a character that is written in Unicode? I am not able to fully explain the question. But it seems like you people are getting the gist. And finally, if it's not possible without explicitly checking for each character and it's Unicode, then I would like to know.

Comment: What do you mean by "the string contains a character that is written in Unicode"? If you are "not able to fully explain the question" how do you expect anyone to answer it? I for one am not "getting the gist"!

Comment: You can see the code I have implemented, right? Just remove the explicit checking of each characters and replacing some with it's unicode equivalence in the output and you get the question.

Comment: You seem determined to ignore what everyone is telling you.  `\u003e` is another way of writing `>`.  They are the same literal value.  You **cannot** detect it by any means, because **it is not different** from writing `>`.  If a program had `int a = 3;` and `int b = 2 + 1;`, would you be asking for a way to determine whether `a` and `b` are different?  Of course not, because they are exactly the same value.

Comment: Okay. I guess I didn't understand,

Comment: Can you explain why you believed that this mattered in the first place? Perhaps you have a completely different question.

Comment: Okay. There are specific Unicode characters (\u003e, \u003c, \u0026) that were being sorted and replaced in a specific way. My aim was to create a solution that could handle these Unicode characters dynamically without explicitly checking for each one individually. By identifying the Unicode characters programmatically, the solution could adapt to any input string containing such characters without requiring manual intervention.

Answer (score -1):

(removed my previous 2 answers)
After thinking on it for a bit, this is the best solution I can think of which give the exact output you mention in the main post:
`Output: ["(01FJL]x","25Mmnp",")-58Fg{","%*0KPQW]q",",:\u003e@@Amn","7\u003cCNR_aq","\u00268ANOQRx","!14?KTgiss{~",""#$M^_dlmprw"]`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> input =
      Arrays.asList(
          "xL01(F]J",
          "2pn5Mm",
          "-5)8gF{",
          "KWq0P]*%Q",
          "n@,:\u003eAm@",
          "\u003cRN_qCa7",
          "8Qx\u0026RAON",
          "gT~s!1s?4i{K",
          "w\"r^d_#l$Mmp"); // the `"` needs to be escaped,
                            // it isn't in your input, 
                            // but it should be to work in a string

  List<String> sortedStrings = input.stream()
                                    .map(Main::sortString)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println("Input: " + formatList(input));
  System.out.println("Output: " + formatList(sortedStrings));
}

private static String sortString(String str) {
  char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
  Arrays.sort(chars);
  return new String(chars);
}

private static String formatList(List<String> list) {
  return list.stream()
             .map(Main::escapeUnicodeCharacters)
             .map(str -> "\"" + str.replace("\"\"", "\"\\\"\"") + "\"")
             .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
}

private static String escapeUnicodeCharacters(String str) {
  return str.replace(">", "\\u003e")
            .replace("<", "\\u003c")
            .replace("&", "\\u0026");
}
```

Comment: Ya. But still, I have to previously set all those special characters in that HashMap. This is not the actual way I want to do. Anyway thank you for the workaround.

Comment: I think it's premature to answer when we don't know what the Question is actually asking.

Comment: @tgdavies yeah, I was to eager to answer more SO questions, and didn't fully think through the question before answering, I also didn't know that strings treated escaped unicode like you and @trincot mention in the main post comments. Since my regex idea won't work due to this, I think the best way to get the exact output mentioned in the top of the question would be to use `.map()` to `.replace()` any converted unicode in the sorted string back into their escape sequence for printing. I've again changed my answer with this change, and it does match the exact `Output: ...` in the question.

Comment: Thank you @gmifflen . It solves the issue but still uses explicit character escaping/checking. Thank you for the help. If you find any way of solving this without that, please let me know.

Comment: @BishalShrestha I don't believe there is a way to reliably (or at all) determine if a string contains characters originally written using Unicode escapes. This is because both the escaped characters and their directly typed counterparts are stored identically in memory after compilation, so once the code is running it's impossible to distinguish whether a character was typed directly or represented by a Unicode escape.

Comment: An analogy would be 2 different brands of the same colour of paint. It doesn't matter if it's X-Corp paint(`>`) or Y-Corp paint(`\u003e`), they'll both end up as the same coral colour(`0xe9`) once they are on the wall.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the scenario. I guess you are right. I think understanding how characters are interpreted by the compiler during compile time is crucial and in my understanding there is no way of determining whether it's `<` or `\u003e` . Thank you @gmifflen .